# What is a good reference for rigorous Electromagnetism and Electrodynamics?

Tags: reference-request, physics, mathematical-physics, book-recommendation

Is there any good book on Electromagnetism from a more mathematical point of view? By this I mean a book which makes use of differential forms and maybe De Rham cohomology. I was also searching for something that would include E&M in the big picture of Gauge theories.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here are a couple of books that aren't necessarily meant for mathematicians but are pretty mathematical:

- *Foundations of Classical Electrodynamics: Charge, Flux, and Metric* by Friedrich W. Hehl and Yuri N. Obukhov.  This book is probably closest to what you're looking for.  It is very rigorous, even starting by stating a set of axioms for classical electrodynamics.  This book not only uses differential forms, but tensors in their full(ish) glory.
- *Gauge Fields, Knots & Gravity* by John Baez and Javier P. Muniain.  This book is specifically about gauge fields and classical field theory.  The first third of the book is on E&M and is an introduction to differential forms and de Rham theory.

Comment: Thank you very much. I knew about the second one but yeah, I was looking for something like the first one.

Comment: No problem. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add a book I've been using lately: *From Calculus to Cohomology* by Ib Madsen and Jørgen Tomehave. This book covers those topics on the second half of the book (the first half is mainly introductory and develops the tools).